# New-Mailbox command does not accept the -Equipment argument

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I'm attempting to create new resources in Exchange Online via a script and it works if I type the line manually but when I run the script, the command New-Mailbox suddenly can't accept the "-Equipment" argument.

Script fails on the following row:

```
New-Mailbox -Name "$($Resource)" -$($Type)
```

Error shows following:

```
A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-Equipment'.
 + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-Mailbox], ParameterBindingException"
```

Answer (score 2):

PowerShell interprets `-$($Type)` as a string argument rather than a parameter name. Use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) to conditionally pass parameters like this:

```
$extraParams = @{ $Type = $true }
New-Mailbox -Name "$($Resource)" @extraParams
```

I'm not sure which other types of mailboxes are available in Exchange Online, but you'll probably want to figure that out and apply some input validation:

```
param(
    [string]$Resource,

    [ValidateSet('Equipment','Person','Room')]
    [string]$Type
)

# do other stuff here

# If someone passed a wrong kind of `$Type`, the script would have already thrown an error
$extraParams = @{ $Type = $true }
New-Mailbox -Name "$($Resource)" @extraParams
```